# How to update progressbar from another thread class?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, progress-bar

I am currently working on a simple neural network in Python and I'm having trouble with Tkinter and multithreading.

I have 2 classes, one for the interface and the other one for the computing work.

I have in my interface class a progress bar and a button that calls a function in the computing work class in an other thread. I'd like to have this called function to update the value of my progressBar. (For each 1000 item tested for example)

So this I my code (simplified):

Interface:

```
class UInterface:

    def __init__(self):
       self.window = Tk()
       self.nh = NetworkHelper()
       self.progress_value = 0
       self.test_result = Label(window, text="").grid(row=0, column =1)
       Button(self.window, text="Test", command=partial(self.test)).grid(row=1, column =1)
       self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(orient="horizontal", maximum=117, mode="determinate")
       self.progress.grid(row=3, column =1)
       self.window.mainloop()

    def test(self):
       pool = ThreadPool(processes=1)

       async_result = pool.apply_async(self.nh.test)

       while results == None
          self.progress["value"] = self.progress_value 
          self.window.update()

       results = async_result.get()

       self.test_result.config(text=str(results) + "% of good answers")
```

And here is my test function in NetworkHelper class doing the hard work:

```
def test(self):
    total_answer = 0
    good_answer = 0
    # preparing data and testing
    for i in range(self.data_test_length):
        ## Some testing 
        total_answer += 1
        ## TODO Update progress_value in class Interface

    return good_answer/total_answer
```

I tried a few stuff, like calling a function in Interface from the NH.test but since it's not the same thread, I can't update anything. I also tried Queues but couldn't manage to make it work.

Comment: Are you sure you are updating `self.progress_value`? From the code you posted it seems you didn't modify it and it stays at 0.

Comment: No I am not, I want to update it at " ## Update progress_value in class interface" line in the nh.test function. That's the trick I am looking for

Comment: Maybe you can pass your `UInterface` object so you can access it inside `NetworkHelper`?

Comment: Oh, thanks ! Just didn't thought about it but I just tried it and it works like a charm ! Thank you very much !